# How i can access elements in OpenCV::Mat?

Tags: android, opencv3.0

Actually i am using OpenCV::inRange() to detect a certain color in image.This function returns a OpenCV::Mat.I am having problems accessing individual elements in OpenCV::Mat.

Answer (score 0):

To access individual elements use `mat.at<float>(row, col)`. Replace float with the correct data type and row and col with y and x.

Comment: Does not work which version of OpenCV has this method?

Comment: Since 3.0. What language do you use?

Comment: I am using Java in android

Comment: You should add a Java tag then. I assumed you are using C++ (because you use C++ syntax).